# C++ global and local variables

Tags: c++, variables, scope

I have encountered the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int i = 1;
int main(int argc,char ** argv)
{
    int i = i;
    cout<<i<<endl; // which i?
    return 0;
}
```

It can pass the compile, but gives the wrong answer, how to explain this?

Comment: what answer does it give and what did you expect?

Comment: Why don't you just write code that will unambiguously tell you which `i` you are printing out?

Comment: @jsantander The result is random, I wonder why it can pass the compile.

Comment: @juanchopanza This is a code I happened to seen on Internet.

Comment: The reason has been indicated in the answers: `int i=i` declares a local variable that overshadows the global i... and assign it to itself (not to the global value)... that's why you get random values

Comment: Your compiler should warn that you are using an uninitialized variable.  That warning is apparently not enabled by default for your compiler.  Enable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Local variable is accessible,
 analogous to calling two people with a same name, one inside the room, and one outside the room.
The one who is in the scope you are trying to access it , hears it.

Answer (score 6):

The `int i = i;` statement in `main()` declares a local variable that hides the global variable.

It initializes itself with itself (which has an indeterminate value).  So the global `i` simply isn't used.

Comment: This is the only answer currently (out of 4) that addresses the key problem.

Comment: To illustrate further, in `int i = i`, local `i` is declared when parsing advances to the latter `i` (e.g. the right hand expression), so the latter `i` would reference the newly declared local `i` instead of the global `i`. And it's not initialized. That line is simply equivalent to `int i` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in the innermost scope will override variables with the same Name without warning.

Comment: Do you mean that the variable i in main function are the same and they are not initialized?

Answer (score 1):

Variables in deeper scopes will override the variables with the same name in a higher scope. To access a global variable, precede the name with `::`

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int i=i;
    return 0;
}
```

is correct.

So in your program, the global `i` is ignored when the local `i` is encountered and it is initialized to itself. You'll get a garbage value as a result.

Answer (score 0):

When you have two variable with same name, one is global and other is local. Then in this case local variable will get in use only in that particular scope. And global variable is unused.

Now, coming to your problem

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int i = 1;//Global Variable decleration
int main(int argc,char ** argv)
{
    int i = i; // Local to main
    cout<<i<<endl; // which i?
    return 0;
}
```

`int i = i;` compiles without any error but when you run the program it will produce error because local `i` has indeterminate value.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, it is possible to access the global variable if you have a local variable with the same name but you have to use the scope resolution operator `::`

change the line:

`int i = i;`

to

`int i = ::i;`

and the program will compile and work

Answer (score 0):

The concept most answers are describing is called [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).