# How to calculate mean using calling function in C++?

Tags: c++

The functions are `getInputN()`, `calculateMean()` & `displayData()`.

So to be really clear, these are the requirements.

- `getInputN` function: Should accept the number of the value, N as an integer as argument and ask the user to enter the value of N number. Then, return the sum of the value as a double.
- `calculateMean` function: Should accept the number of the value, N and sum of the value as arguments. Then return the mean as a double.
- `displayData` function: Should accept the mean as argument. Then, display them in the appropriate message on screen. No return value required for this function.

If I run the code, it will display Average = inf

p/s: I'm really sorry for the confusing question at first. I'm really new to this website and this is my very first question. It took me some times to figure out things to ask properly in this platform. I hope you guys understand and once again, sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you for the helps too :)

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getInputN(int n);
float calculateMean (int n, float sum);
float displayData(double mean);

int i,n;
float sum = 0.0, num[50];
double mean;

int main()
{
    getInputN(n);
    calculateMean (n, sum);
    displayData(mean);

    return 0;
}

int getInputN(int n)
{
    int i;
    float num[50];

    //User enter the number of value
    cout << "Enter the numbers of data: ";
    cin >> n;
    
    //if user input more than 50 numbers
    while (n > 50 || n <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid! Enter the number in range of (1 to 50)." << endl;
        cout << "Enter the number of data: ";
        cin >> n;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ". Enter number: ";
        cin >> num[i];
        sum += num[i];
    }

    return n;
}

    //function to calculate the mean
    float calculateMean (int n, float sum)
    {
    
        mean = sum/n;
    
        return mean;
    }

    //function to display the mean
    float displayData (double mean)
    {
        cout << "Average = " << mean;
    }
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: It's never too soon to stop using global variables.

Comment: The parameter `int n` in `getInputN` shadows the global `int n`. So `getInputN` doesn't update the global variable, it just returns a value. So when you call `calculateMean(n, sum)` using the global `n` as an argument, it doesn't have any valid value. Your functions have return types, you should be using them in your calling code.

Comment: And calculateMean divides a sum (which you never added anything to, so it's zero) by a number n which you never initialized at all. It seems a lot like you don't really understand how to use return values at all yet.

Comment: The output that I got is Average = inf. The answer supposed to get the mean of the input numbers. I think the arguments and return value are all messed up lol

Comment: Actually, question: Is this even defined behavior? The uninitialized global `n` is being passed to `getInputN` by value. Even though `getInputN` doesn't attempt to read the value of its parameter, does this still form UB?

Comment: @Useless Doesn't `getInputN` actually update `sum`? There's no shadowing for _that_ global variable.

Comment: Oh, you're right - I didn't notice it was updating the only global it _didn't_ have any business touching (given it _should_ update `n` and `num` but doesn't)

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on exactly what your lecturer expects `getInputN` to do? What is its argument(s) supposed to be? What is its return value supposed to be? What, if anything, is it supposed to do to global variables? There's a ton of different ways you could rewrite `getInputN` and `main` based on the answers to that, and "it accepts arguments" is not sufficient to narrow it down at all.

Answer (score 1):

The argument `int n` in the function `getInputN` is shadowing (hiding) the global variable `n`. This prevents the global variable from being updated and `sum` is divided by zero (the default value of gloval variable without explicit initialization).

If you want to pass data using gloval variables, the arguments should be removed because one of that (`n` as descrived above) is harmful and other are redundant.

Also the function `displayData` is declared to return `float` but didn't execute any `return` statement. This invokes *undefined behavior*. I fixed this by changing its return type to `void`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getInputN();
float calculateMean ();
void displayData();

int i,n;
float sum = 0.0, num[50];
double mean;

int main()
{
    getInputN();
    calculateMean ();
    displayData();

    return 0;
}

int getInputN()
{
    int i;
    float num[50];

    //User enter the number of value
    cout << "Enter the numbers of data: ";
    cin >> n;
    
    //if user input more than 50 numbers
    while (n > 50 || n <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid! Enter the number in range of (1 to 50)." << endl;
        cout << "Enter the number of data: ";
        cin >> n;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ". Enter number: ";
        cin >> num[i];
        sum += num[i];
    }

    return n;
}

//function to calculate the mean
float calculateMean ()
{

    mean = sum/n;

    return mean;
}

//function to display the mean
void displayData ()
{
    cout << "Average = " << mean;
}
```

This fix will make the code work, but there should be better design without usage of global variables. [References](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) is useful to have functions modify things given as arguments and [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is useful to return "arrays".

Comment: Oh ok I see... Actually in the question, my lecturer said the three functions getInput(N), calculateMean() & displayData accept arguments. So, how is that being implemented in the code? Btw, thank you so much for the answer! Appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `n` in `int getInputN(int n)` is used in the function instead of the global `n` declared. As such, using **global** `n` (which is <strike>uninitialized till that point</strike> initialized to 0) to calculate `mean = sum/n` will lead to a <strike>`undefined behavior`</strike> `divide by 0` error, resulting in `inf`.

More info :

- [Uninitialized variable behaviour in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172416/uninitialized-variable-behaviour-in-c)
- [C++ global and local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22742396/c-global-and-local-variables)

Also, the function `float displayData (double mean)` doesn't return any value, causing another `undefined behavior`.

More info :

- [Why does flowing off the end of a non-void function without returning a value not produce a compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-does-flowing-off-the-end-of-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-no)

Modified code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getInputN();
void calculateMean();
void displayData();

int i,n;
float sum = 0.0, num[50];
double mean;

int main()
{
    getInputN();
    calculateMean();
    displayData();

    return 0;
}

void getInputN()
{
    int i;
    float num[50];

    //User enter the number of value
    cout << "Enter the numbers of data: ";
    cin >> n;

    //if user input more than 50 numbers
    while (n > 50 || n <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid! Enter the number in range of (1 to 50)." << endl;
        cout << "Enter the number of data: ";
        cin >> n;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ". Enter number: ";
        cin >> num[i];
        sum += num[i];
    }
}

//function to calculate the mean
void calculateMean ()
{
    mean = sum/n;
}

//function to display the mean
void displayData ()
{
    cout << "Average = " << mean;
}
```

Result :

```
Enter the numbers of data: 3
1. Enter number: 1
2. Enter number: 3
3. Enter number: 6
Average = 3.33333
```

Furthermore, if you don't use the numbers for anything else, declaring a `float num[50];` is quite pointless. Also, noted that using global variable and [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is not recommended.

```
#include <iostream>

const int maxn = 50;
const int minn = 1;

int main()
{
    int n; std::cout << "Enter N : "; std::cin >> n;
    while (n < minn || n > maxn) {std::cout << "Invalid. Re-enter N : "; std::cin >> n;}

    double sum = 0; int tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { std::cout << "Enter number " << i+1 << " : "; std::cin >> tmp; sum += tmp;}

    std::cout << "Average : " << sum/n;
}
```

Result :

```
Enter N : 3
Enter number 1 : 25
Enter number 2 : 97
Enter number 3 : 111
Average : 77.6667
```

Comment: The *global* `n` has *static storage duration*, so it is *zero-initialized* by default. ([N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 8.5 Initializers 9) `mean = sum/n` invokes *undefined behavior* because it is division by zero. (N3337 5.6 Multiplicative operators)

Comment: @MikeCAT my mistake, I'm going to modified it now.

Comment: Oh ok I see... Actually in the question, my lecturer said the three functions getInput(N), calculateMean() & displayData accept arguments. So, how is that being implemented in the code? Btw, thank you so much for the answer! Appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @daisy98 If you have additional requirements for what the functions' signatures should be and how they should work, please edit the actual question to include them. Otherwise people will have to guess what the intended behavior of the functions is.

Comment: @daisy98 "Actually in the question, my lecturer said the three functions getInput(N), calculateMean() & displayData accept arguments." But what for? Well I mean as `sum`, `mean` and `n` are global variables anyway and can be read by any function so `float calculateMean (int n, float sum)` and `float displayData (double mean)` will work the same, `int getInputN(int n)` leads to some problem. So what are you using those arguments **for**? If you has other requirements, edit your question to include them, else, including unnecessary arguments can lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing how the functions are behaved, we can write implementations that work nicely and don't use any global variables at all.

```
#include <iostream>

double getInputN(int n);
double calculateMean(int n, double sum);
void displayData(double mean);

int main()
{   
    //User enter the number of value
    int numEntries;
    std::cout << "Enter the numbers of data: ";
    std::cin >> numEntries;

    //if user input more than 50 numbers
    while (numEntries > 50 || numEntries <= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid! Enter the number in range of (1 to 50)." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter the number of data: ";
        std::cin >> numEntries;
    }

    // Get user input
    double sum = getInputN(numEntries);

    double mean = calculateMean(numEntries, sum);

    displayData(mean);

    return 0;
}

double getInputN(int n)
{
    double sum = 0.;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        double userInput;
        std::cout << i + 1 << ". Enter number: ";
        std::cin >> userInput;
        sum += userInput;
    }

    return sum;
}

//function to calculate the mean
double calculateMean(int n, double sum)
{

    double mean = sum / n;

    return mean;
}

//function to display the mean
void displayData(double mean)
{
    std::cout << "Average = " << mean;
}
```

Let's go into some more detail on each of the changes.

First, I've changed the signatures of all of your functions. `getInputN` is supposed to return a `double`, not an `int`. `calculateMean` is supposed to accept and return a `double`, not a `float`. And `displayData` isn't required to return anything, it doesn't make sense for it to return anything, and therefore I've made its return type `void`.

Second, note that I've moved the code for figuring out how many entries to enter from `getInputN` into `main`. The reason for this is that the sole argument to `getInputN` is "how many inputs should we get?", so we need to know its value *before* we call `getInputN`.

Third, note how I've used the return values from each function in the calling code. In `main`, when I write `double sum = getInputN(numEntries);`, that declares a variable `sum` and stores the return value of `getInputN(numEntries)` to `sum`. When you just write `getInputN(n);`, the return value from `getInputN` is discarded. By storing it in a variable in `main`, I can then pass its value to another function, like in the next line where I've written `double mean = calculateMean(numEntries, sum);`.

Fourth, note how the requirements of the question are such that I no longer use any kind of array whatsoever. `getInputN` doesn't bother tracking each individual entry, because all we care about is the final sum at the end.

Comment: @daisy98 That sounds like an issue with your environment. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921297/codeblocks-c-build-permission-denied-collect2-exe) will help?

Comment: Oh I got it! The error came from me, sorry. Thank you so much for helping me from the start :) Really appreciate it!